# Bi-invariant Riemannian metrics on So(n)

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Defining the inner product - 1/2 tr(XY) on the lie algebra so(n)(skew symmetric matrices) is one way to introduce a bi-invariant metric on So(n) since the inner product is ad-invariant. Are there any other non-trivial differentiable bi-invariant metrics on So(n)?
Also, is the above defined metric equivalent to the metric induced on So(n) when it is seen as a fiber bundle over So(n-1)?
Any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: What map $So(n) \to So(n-1)$ are you talking about here?

Comment: Exact map is slightly tedious to write but the quotient So(n)/So(n-1)
is (n-1) sphere and we can use it to write So(n) as a fiber bundle over So(n-1) where the fiber is the (n-1) sphere. Using this, we can inductively define a metric on So(n).

Comment: sreedhar: $SO(n)$ fibers over $S^n$ with fiber $SO(n-1)$, not the other way around. Just think about trying to fiber $SO(3)$ over $SO(2)=S^1$. 

Comment: When $n=4$, there is a $2$-parameter family of bi-invariant metrics on $\mathrm{SO}(4)$, but for $n\not=4$, the bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is unique up to a constant multiple.

Comment: @Robert, Is the proof of your claim can be explained quickly to illustrate 4 is special dimension?

Comment: @GB:  Yes.  The point is that, for $n\not=2,4$, the Lie algebra ${\frak{so}}(n)$ is simple.  In particular, the representation $\mathrm{Ad}:\mathrm{SO}(n)\to \mathrm{Aut}\bigl({\frak{so}}(n)\bigr)$ is irreducible, so there is, up to multiples, only one $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant quadratic form on ${\frak{so}}(n)$, and hence, up to multiples, only one bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ when $n\not=4$.  However, because ${\frak{so}}(4)\simeq {\frak{so}}(3)\oplus{\frak{so}}(3)$, there is a $2$-parameter family of $\mathrm{Ad}$-invariant quadratic forms on ${\frak{so}}(4)$.

Comment: @Misha You are right, its the other way round. Am I right when I say that given a point p on So(n), the differential of the local trivialization gives a isomorphism from tangent space at p to the tangent space at (p1,p2) where p1 and p2 are points corresponding to p in S(n-1) and So(n-1) respectively? And that the tangent space at (p1,p2) is the direct sum of tangent spaces at p1 and p2?
If this is true, we can use this map to define an inner product on tangent space at p(given an inner product on So(n-1)) and  hence a metric on So(n). Will this metric be bi-invariant?
@Robert: Thank you.

Comment: Seems almost dead. Anyway, can somebody tell me if the above Bi-invariant metric has a nice expression in the local chart (V,exp) where exp is the exponential map and V is a neighborhood in so(n)(skew symmetric matrices) where exp is a diffeomorphism?